# Помогите разобраться с методами массива JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, redux

```
let initialState = {
  questions: [

    {
      name: 'Вопрос 1 ',
      id: 1,
      answers: [
        { name: '1608', isRight: true, id: 1, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '1871', isRight: false, id: 2, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '1504', isRight: false, id: 3, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '1927', isRight: false, id: 4, isSelected: undefined },
      ],
    },

    {
      name: 'Вопрос 2',
      id: 2,
      answers: [
        { name: '1', isRight: false, id: 1, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '2', isRight: false, id: 2, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '3', isRight: false, id: 3, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '4', isRight: true, id: 4, isSelected: undefined },
      ],
    },
  ],
  rightDoneQuestions:[],

}
```

reducer

```
  if(action.type ===SET_RIGHT_DONE_QUESTIONS ){
    return {
      ...state,
      rightDoneQuestions:???
  }
```

Помогите мне написать reducer. Мы должны рассмотреть массив questions. Для каждого объекта в нем рассматриваем массив answers. Для каждого объекта answers рассматриваем условие: если у этого объекта (isRight===true)&&(isSelected === true), то тогда нам нужно этот объект закинуть в массив rightDoneQuestions.
Подскажите, как правильно это сделать?(какие методы массива использовать?)

Comment: Я имел в виду, что я использую Redux и мне необходимо обновить состояние приложения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let state = {
  questions: [

    {
      name: 'Вопрос 1 ',
      id: 1,
      answers: [
        { name: '1608', isRight: true, id: 1, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '1871', isRight: true, id: 2, isSelected: true },
        { name: '1504', isRight: false, id: 3, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '1927', isRight: false, id: 4, isSelected: true },
      ],
    },

    {
      name: 'Вопрос 2',
      id: 2,
      answers: [
        { name: '1', isRight: false, id: 1, isSelected: true },
        { name: '2', isRight: true, id: 2, isSelected: true },
        { name: '3', isRight: false, id: 3, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '4', isRight: true, id: 4, isSelected: undefined },
      ],
    },
  ],
  rightDoneQuestions:[],
}

console.log({
  ...state,
  rightDoneQuestions : state.questions.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  obj.answers.forEach(answer => {
  if (answer.isRight === true && answer.isSelected === true) acc.push(answer)})
   return acc;
   },[])
})
```